# Preprocessor and macros

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define macro(n, a, i, m) m##a##i##n
#define MAIN macro(n, a, i, m)
int MAIN()
{

    printf("GeeksQuiz");

    return 0;
}
```

Hello people
In this question the output is geeksquiz as it says that main is first replaced by macro then again replaced. Where does the actual replacement take place ? 
Isn't it just defining functions ? 
Thank you

Comment: Replacement takes place where it *always* takes place with macros: the preprocessing phase. There is only one function declared and defined in this code: `main`.

Comment: It's simply replacing `MAIN` with `main`. Which you can see (if using gcc or clang) by using the `-E` option and looking at the preprocessor output.

Comment: If there was some other name of the function other than macro , would it have done the same or defined it as different functions.

Comment: Try it, change both `macro` to something else.

Comment: How do we know when the main function is getting replaced. In cases ive seen that they are defined as separate functions, is it due to macro or MAIN ? ( Sorry new to C here )

Comment: Crap like this is not worth spending time on as a beginner. I would instead recommend to focus on learning how to best structure your programs and to learn the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

This takes place in the fourth phase of translation (known as the preprocessing phase) by the compiler.

You can read up on "[Phases of Translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases)"

> If there was some other name of the function other than macro , would it have done the same or defined it as different functions

Yes. "macro" can be changed to some other name.

```
#define some_other_name(n, a, i, m) m##a##i##n
#define MAIN some_other_name(n, a, i, m)
```

> How do we know when the main function is getting replaced. In cases ive seen that they are defined as separate functions, is it due to macro or MAIN ? ( Sorry new to C here )

Because MAIN is defined as a MACRO and the MACRO expansion is resulting in `main`.